# XPath Search relating to Attributes

Tags: xpath, attributes

I want to create an `XPath` query that returns cast members whose "job" is "Actor" and whose "order" is between "0" and "4" from the following `XML`. I'm finding it hard to create a query that does both.

```
<cast>
    <person name="David Silverman" character="" job="Director" order="0"/>
    <person name="James L. Brooks" character="" job="Author" order="0"/>
    <person name="Dan Castellaneta" character="Homer J. Simpson" job="Actor" order="0"/>
    <person name="Julie Kavner" character="Marge Simpson" job="Actor" order="1"/>
    <person name="Nancy Cartwright" character="Bart Simpson" job="Actor" order="2"/>
    <person name="Yeardley Smith" character="Lisa Simpson" job="Actor" order="3"/>
    <person name="Dan Castellaneta" character="Krusty the Clown" job="Actor" order="4"/>
    <person name="Hank Azaria" character="Moe Szyslak" job="Actor" order="5"/>
    <person name="Dan Castellaneta" character="Apu Nahasapeemapetilon" job="Actor" order="6"/>
</cast>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cast/person[@job="Actor" and @order >= 0 and @order <= 3]
```

returns the four Simpsons you want.

Comment: That worked a treat.....so simple, and I feel so silly. Thanks a bunch. Great help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `//cast/person[@job='Actor' and position()<3]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. I am aware of using the @job to access the job attribute, but I was wondering if it were possible to also specify a further constraint of [@order >= '0' and @order <='4'] while at the same time specifying [@job ='Actor'] in a single query

Comment: @user644347 I'm new to XPath, and I have noticed the other two solutions used `order` instead of `position`, which leads me to believe I have used the less correct solution. Anyone explain it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine your predicates `//cast/person[@job='Actor' and @order>=0 and @order<=3]`