# How to find a DOM Node using its attributes

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom

I have parsed my *HTML/JSP* into *DOM at compile time* using JAVA. Now I have the ***w3c.dom.Document*** object with me, let's say for the below HTML

```
.....
  ....
<input type="text" name="EnterName"/>
<select name="SelectOptions">
<option>First</option>
<option>Second</option>
</select>
 ......
.......
```

I know the attributes values of the elements. Here *"EnterName"* is the *"name"* attributes value of the node "input".

Suppose I have attributes values of all nodes available in DOM (like "EnterName", "SelectOptions" of above HTML), how do I can get a node in which a particular attribute is available with the given value. Thanks

**EDIT :**

> I will never know whats the HTML contents. My program should run on
>   given list of HTML/JSP files and I have with me some element names. 
>   Here the element name refers to the label/name of the fields available
>   in the HTML/JSP. So I need to traverse through all the files get the
>   node where it has the same label/name and get the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse("yourDocumentName");
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nlList = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (int indx= 0; indx < nList.getLength(); indx++) {
       Element eElement = (Element) nList.item(indx);
       if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("EnterName")){
              System.out.println("EnterName: " + eElement.getNodeValue());
       }
    }

    NodeList nlList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (int indx= 0; indx < nList1.getLength(); indx++) {
       Element eElement = (Element) nList1.item(indx);
       if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("SelectOptions")){
              System.out.println("SelectOptions: " + eElement.getNodeValue());
       }
    }
```

**If you could add the "id" to your elements then its much easier:**

```
 <input type="text" name="EnterName" id="name"/>
 <select name="SelectOptions" id="options">
  ...


  Element nameElement = doc.getElementbyId("name");
  System.out.println("EnterName: " + nameElement.getNodeValue());
  Element selectElement = doc.getElementbyId("name");
  System.out.println("SelectOptions: " + selectElement.getNodeValue());
```

Comment: Please check my EDIT on question and suggest

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have traversed the nodes and find the appropriate attribute with the value and got what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom attributes in html for example to differentiate betweeen html components

```
<input type="text" name="EnterName" myattr1="yes"/>
<select name="SelectOptions" myattr2="yes">
<option>First</option>
<option>Second</option>
</select>
```

on basis of custom attributes you can check and differentiate on the HTML components...

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the HTML.That is not in my control, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can say something like this:

```
Element input = .... documene.getElementByTagName("input");
Attribute eneterName = root.getAttributeNode("EnterName");
String s = enterName.getXXXValue();
```

Please refer the API to get the correct method to retreive the value.

Comment: Please check my EDIT on question and suggest

Answer (score 1):

Normally you search for attributes by their name, e.g. "name", not by their value, e.g. "EnterName".  So you would typically go

```
String valueForName = myElement.getAttribute("name");
```

For anything very complicated, I use XPath.  Which works for what you want.  Here's a blog that looks like just what you want (though it's not Java, it's close enough):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2007/03/13/quick-tip-using-xpath-to-find-nodes-by-attribute-value.aspx

Here's a [similar non-Java Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191652/xpath-search-relating-to-attributes)

Elaborating in Java, its a bit tedious, but, roughly...

```
XPathFactory anXPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = anXPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xpe = xpath.compile("your xpath goes here");
String finallyIGetSomething = (String) xpe.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Haven't tested this for your case so caveat emptor

Comment: Please check my EDIT on question and suggest